# how to start the app on power button press in android

Tags: events, click, android-powermanager

I want to launch(open) my app on single click of power button of android phone, How we detect single click event on power button. I tried onKey event but it detect only long click not single click. Anybody, have any idea? is there any broadcast receiver method for that?